# How can I patch a resource in base from my overlay with kustomize and let the replacements in base also run?

Tags: kustomize

I have `base/kustomization.yaml`

```
resources:
  - ...
...
replacements:
  - source:
      kind: Ingress
      name: myingress2
      fieldPath: spec.rules.0.host
    targets:
      - select:
          kind: Deployment
          name: mydeployment
        fieldPaths:
          - spec.template.spec.containers.[name=flask].env.[name=MYVAR].value
```

Then in my overlay `staging/kustomization.yaml` I have:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ../base
patches:
  - target:
      kind: Ingress
      name: myingress2
    path: ingress.json
```

where `ingress.json`:

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/spec/rules/0/host",
    "value": "myhostname.example.com"
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/spec/tls/0/hosts",
    "value": ["myhostname.example.com"]
  }
]
```

When I run `kustomize build` I can see that the `ingress2` has been patched but the value from `ingress2` have not been copied (via the replacement in base) to `mydeployment`.

So it seems like the `replacements:` in `base/` happens before the `patches` in `overlay/`.

Is there any other way to achieve this, or I need to copy the same replacements to the `overlay/`?

I just want to set the hostname in one place and it should be in the ingress `.spec.tls.hosts`, `.spec.rules.host` and in the deployment as an environment variable.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour of Kustomize is to build the base, generate a Yaml output and then give this output to the overlays. The replacement happens before the patch in your case.

Comment: You might want to look at Kustomize "Components".

Comment: Or Helm which simplifies this a lot with templating. :)